# Partial update on Tensor in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to run multiple convolutions on image in TensorFlow and then concatenate results. Because `tf.concat` allocates new tensor I sometimes run into `ResourceExhaustedError` (current solution is to change `batch_size` to smaller value).

So here is my question. Is there a way to create big tensor (I know all dimensions in advance) and then assign results of convolutions to it (part by part to avoid concatenating and memory allocation)? Or maybe there is other more efficient way of doing this?

Something like:

```
convs = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([..])
tf.update(convs, [..], tf.nn.conv2d(..) + biases1)
tf.update(convs, [..], tf.nn.conv2d(..) + biases2)
^^^^^^^^^         ^^offsets
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to do this - TensorFlow objects are immutable by design.

There might be another way to accomplish what you want (and it'd be interesting to know about cases that are running out of memory for future improvements).

Comment: I am playing with TensorFlow following a Deep Learning course on udacity. Error pops up for obvious reasons. I have only `2GB` on `GPU` so when I try to run computations with more convolutions (I tried 3) on validation set with 10k examples it first allocates `10k*28*28*8 (*3)` floats, when I concatenate those results it allocates another `10k*28*28*8*3` floats and at the end I need to reshape this Tensor so it allocates again the same amount of memory ending up with error. It kind of wastes memory for the same data. With smaller batches it's not a problem and everything works great.

Comment: With 10k examples, smaller batches is *definitely* the way to go, particularly if it's just for the validation run.